# R match column name and pull values

Tags: r, loops, merge, match

I am trying to lookup the values associated with a participant experiment and sum them for each participant's participation in each experiment.

If the participant has a 1 in column A, it means they were exposed to experiment A. I then want to pull in the 3 values associated with experiment A, and start summing those values across each experiment exposure for each participant.

df:

```
Participant   A   B 
 1     1    1
 2     1    0
 3     0    1
```

My lookup dataframe:

```
Experiment   Val1   Val2   Val3  
 A     1.1   1.2   1.3
 B     1.0   1.1   1.5
```

For a result of df:

```
Id   A   B   Val1   Val2   Val3 
 1     1    1    2.1    2.3    2.8
 2     1    0    1.1   1.2   1.3
 3     0    1    1.0   1.1   1.5
```

My true dataset has 64 instances of experiments, with 7,000 participants. My shorthand of what this would look like would be:

For each row,
For each column,

If column i=1, match columnName to lookup$Experiment

add Val1:Val3 in a temp array

then paste temp array into df

Any help would be appreciated! I'm not sure if this is a match or merge function.

Data

```
df = structure(list(Participant = 1:3, A = c(1L, 1L, 0L), B = c(1L, 
0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Participant", "A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
lookup = structure(list(Experiment = c("A", "B"), Val1 = c(1.1, 1), Val2 = c(1.2, 
1.1), Val3 = c(1.3, 1.5)), .Names = c("Experiment", "Val1", "Val2", 
"Val3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing matrix multiplication. Treating the `Participant` and `Experiment` column as row labels (and *requiring* that the experiment columns of `df` are in the same order as the rows of the lookup table):

```
result = as.matrix(df[, -1]) %*% as.matrix(lookup[, -1])
result = cbind(df[1], result)
result
#   Participant Val1 Val2 Val3
# 1           1  2.1  2.3  2.8
# 2           2  1.1  1.2  1.3
# 3           3  1.0  1.1  1.5
```